# Getting wxImage in a panel

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I've a problem to get a wxImage into a wxPanel. 
I want to create a .exe with some pics in the exe, but I want to avoid to give the PNG-Pics with the exe.

So far, I get the PNGs into the exe with this:

```
wxStaticBitmap *image = new wxStaticBitmap(p_img, wxID_ANY,
    wxBitmap("Bild.png", wxBITMAP_TYPE_PNG),
    wxPoint(0,0),               
    wxSize(width, height);
```

where *p_img* ist the panel and *Bild.png* the picture.

Now, I have followed ***http://wiki.wxwidgets.org/WxImage*** And have now a wxImage... But I don't know how I can get the wxImage in the panel.

```
wxMemoryInputStream istream1(Bild_png, sizeof Bild_png);
wxImage Bild_png(istream1, wxBITMAP_TYPE_PNG);
```

I hope somebody has a idea.

-Casisto

My System:
OS: Win 8.1; wxW 2.9.4; IDE: CodeLite5.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass wxImage into wxBitmap constructor ([wxBitmap Class Reference](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_bitmap.html)):

```
wxBitmap(const wxImage &img, int depth=wxBITMAP_SCREEN_DEPTH)
```

And then you can create wxStaticBitmap. So the code would be something like that:

```
wxImage Bild_png(istream1, wxBITMAP_TYPE_PNG);
wxStaticBitmap *staticBitmap = new wxStaticBitmap(p_img, wxID_ANY, wxBitmap(Bild_png));
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you want to use the images and do not want to ship with exe as a physical files on the file system.
For Windows platform resource only Dll can be used. If you want cross platform you can use following technique:

Convert your PNG file to C++ style array.
And use this C++ array to create wxImage object.

You can download the application to get C++ array from:
http://sourceforge.net/projects/png2cscc/

you will get C++ array like below and put this array in some source file of your project.

```
static const unsigned int the_sizeof_swdXW_bytes = 2304 ;
static const unsigned char the_swdXW_bytes[ the_sizeof_swdXW_bytes ] =
{
    0xED, 0xF8, 0xFC, 0xFF, 0xEB, 0xF4, 0xF9, 0xFF, 0xEF, 0xF3, 0xFC, 0xFF, 0xF4, 0xF7, 0xFF, 0xFF, 
    0xF7, 0xF7, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xEE, 0xF1, 0xFA, 0xFF, 0xEB, 0xF0, 0xF6, 0xFF, 0xF1, 0xF9, 0xFC, 0xFF, 
    0xEE, 0xF8, 0xFA, 0xFF, 0xED, 0xF6, 0xF5, 0xFF, 0xEC, 0xF2, 0xF2, 0xFF, 0xE6, 0xEA, 0xE9, 0xFF, 
    0xE1, 0xE3, 0xE2, 0xFF, 0xDC, 0xE0, 0xDF, 0xFF, 0xDC, 0xE0, 0xE1, 0xFF, 0xD8, 0xDD, 0xD9, 0xFF, 
    0xD0, 0xD1, 0xC9, 0xFF, 0xE2, 0xE2, 0xD6, 0xFF, 0xB4, 0xB1, 0xA8, 0xFF, 0x81, 0x7E, 0x75, 0xFF, 
    0xBA, 0xB5, 0xAF, 0xFF, 0xC2, 0xBD, 0xB7, 0xFF, 0xD0, 0xC9, 0xC3, 0xFF, 0xC6, 0xBF, 0xB9, 0xFF, 
    0xEA, 0xF3, 0xF8, 0xFF, 0xEB, 0xF4, 0xF9, 0xFF, 0xF1, 0xF6, 0xFC, 0xFF, 0xF3, 0xF6, 0xFF, 0xFF, 
    0xF4, 0xF4, 0xFE, 0xFF, 0xEC, 0xEF, 0xF6, 0xFF, 0xE9, 0xEE, 0xF4, 0xFF, 0xF0, 0xF8, 0xFB, 0xFF, 
    0xEE, 0xF6, 0xF8, 0xFF, 0xEC, 0xF2, 0xF2, 0xFF, 0xF7, 0xFB, 0xFA, 0xFF, 0xFE, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 
    0xFB, 0xFB, 0xFB, 0xFF, 0xF5, 0xF7, 0xF6, 0xFF, 0xD9, 0xDD, 0xDE, 0xFF, 0xD2, 0xD7, 0xD3, 0xFF, 
    0xD2, 0xD3, 0xCB, 0xFF, 0xDD, 0xDD, 0xD3, 0xFF, 0xB5, 0xB2, 0xA9, 0xFF, 0x83, 0x80, 0x79, 0xFF, 
    0xBD, 0xB8, 0xB2, 0xFF, 0xC3, 0xBE, 0xB8, 0xFF, 0xD2, 0xCB, 0xC5, 0xFF, 0xC5, 0xBE, 0xB8, 0xFF, 
    0xE6, 0xEE, 0xF1, 0xFF, 0xE9, 0xF1, 0xF4, 0xFF, 0xEF, 0xF2, 0xF7, 0xFF, 0xF1, 0xF1, 0xF9, 0xFF, 
    0xEF, 0xF2, 0xF9, 0xFF, 0xE9, 0xEC, 0xF3, 0xFF, 0xE2, 0xE7, 0xEB, 0xFF, 0xE9, 0xF1, 0xF3, 0xFF, 
    0xE9, 0xEF, 0xEF, 0xFF, 0xF6, 0xFA, 0xF9, 0xFF, 0xE1, 0xE1, 0xE1, 0xFF, 0xA4, 0xA3, 0xA1, 0xFF, 
    0xB5, 0xB3, 0xB4, 0xFF, 0xAC, 0xAA, 0xAB, 0xFF, 0xE9, 0xEA, 0xEC, 0xFF, 0xDB, 0xDD, 0xDC, 0xFF, 
    0xD2, 0xD1, 0xCC, 0xFF, 0xD8, 0xD5, 0xCE, 0xFF, 0xBB, 0xB6, 0xB0, 0xFF, 0x85, 0x80, 0x7C, 0xFF, 
    0xBE, 0xB6, 0xB3, 0xFF, 0xC5, 0xBD, 0xBA, 0xFF, 0xD7, 0xCF, 0xCC, 0xFF, 0xC4, 0xBC, 0xB9, 0xFF, 
    0xE3, 0xE8, 0xEB, 0xFF, 0xE5, 0xEA, 0xED, 0xFF, 0xE6, 0xEA, 0xED, 0xFF, 0xEA, 0xEB, 0xF0, 0xFF, 
    0xEB, 0xEE, 0xF3, 0xFF, 0xE5, 0xE8, 0xED, 0xFF, 0xD9, 0xDE, 0xE1, 0xFF, 0xE6, 0xEC, 0xEC, 0xFF, 
    0xFE, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xC8, 0xC7, 0xC5, 0xFF, 0x04, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x06, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 
    0x07, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x04, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x58, 0x56, 0x57, 0xFF, 0xF5, 0xF5, 0xF3, 0xFF, 
    0xD5, 0xD1, 0xCE, 0xFF, 0xD4, 0xD1, 0xCC, 0xFF, 0xC2, 0xBD, 0xB9, 0xFF, 0x82, 0x7D, 0x79, 0xFF, 
    0xB8, 0xB0, 0xAD, 0xFF, 0xC3, 0xBB, 0xB8, 0xFF, 0xDC, 0xD4, 0xD1, 0xFF, 0xC4, 0xBC, 0xB9, 0xFF, 
    0xE0, 0xE4, 0xE5, 0xFF, 0xE0, 0xE4, 0xE5, 0xFF, 0xE1, 0xE2, 0xE4, 0xFF, 0xE5, 0xE6, 0xEA, 0xFF, 
    0xE5, 0xE9, 0xEC, 0xFF, 0xDF, 0xE3, 0xE4, 0xFF, 0xD5, 0xD9, 0xDA, 0xFF, 0xEF, 0xF1, 0xF0, 0xFF, 
    0xE2, 0xE1, 0xDF, 0xFF, 0x08, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x0A, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x22, 0x12, 0x13, 0xFF, 
    0x23, 0x15, 0x15, 0xFF, 0x15, 0x09, 0x09, 0xFF, 0x04, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0xBD, 0xB9, 0xB6, 0xFF, 
    0xE3, 0xDF, 0xDC, 0xFF, 0xD3, 0xCF, 0xCC, 0xFF, 0xC4, 0xBF, 0xBC, 0xFF, 0x80, 0x7B, 0x78, 0xFF, 
    0xB4, 0xAC, 0xA9, 0xFF, 0xC2, 0xBA, 0xB7, 0xFF, 0xDF, 0xD7, 0xD4, 0xFF, 0xC8, 0xC0, 0xBD, 0xFF, 
    0xDD, 0xDF, 0xDE, 0xFF, 0xDF, 0xE1, 0xE0, 0xFF, 0xDE, 0xE0, 0xDF, 0xFF, 0xE0, 0xE2, 0xE1, 0xFF, 
    0xDE, 0xE2, 0xE3, 0xFF, 0xD8, 0xDC, 0xDB, 0xFF, 0xD3, 0xD7, 0xD6, 0xFF, 0xFA, 0xFA, 0xF8, 0xFF, 
    0x6C, 0x64, 0x62, 0xFF, 0x0A, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x67, 0x53, 0x52, 0xFF, 0x8A, 0x72, 0x72, 0xFF, 
    0x87, 0x72, 0x71, 0xFF, 0x75, 0x63, 0x61, 0xFF, 0x09, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x5F, 0x57, 0x54, 0xFF, 
    0xF3, 0xEE, 0xEA, 0xFF, 0xD2, 0xCF, 0xCA, 0xFF, 0xC3, 0xBE, 0xBB, 0xFF, 0x7F, 0x7A, 0x76, 0xFF, 
    0xB4, 0xAC, 0xA9, 0xFF, 0xC1, 0xB9, 0xB6, 0xFF, 0xDE, 0xD6, 0xD3, 0xFF, 0xCC, 0xC4, 0xC1, 0xFF, 
    0xD7, 0xD7, 0xD5, 0xFF, 0xDC, 0xDC, 0xDA, 0xFF, 0xD9, 0xDB, 0xD8, 0xFF, 0xD9, 0xDB, 0xD8, 0xFF, 
    0xD7, 0xDB, 0xDA, 0xFF, 0xD3, 0xD8, 0xD4, 0xFF, 0xCE, 0xD0, 0xCB, 0xFF, 0xFA, 0xF7, 0xF2, 0xFF, 
    0x46, 0x3B, 0x37, 0xFF, 0x62, 0x4F, 0x4B, 0xFF, 0xB9, 0x9D, 0x9A, 0xFF, 0xCC, 0xAD, 0xAA, 0xFF, 
    0x92, 0x75, 0x71, 0xFF, 0x94, 0x7B, 0x76, 0xFF, 0x3B, 0x28, 0x21, 0xFF, 0x48, 0x3B, 0x33, 0xFF, 
    0xF0, 0xE9, 0xE3, 0xFF, 0xCF, 0xCC, 0xC5, 0xFF, 0xC6, 0xC1, 0xBD, 0xFF, 0x80, 0x7B, 0x75, 0xFF, 
    0xB1, 0xAA, 0xA4, 0xFF, 0xC1, 0xBA, 0xB4, 0xFF, 0xDB, 0xD4, 0xCE, 0xFF, 0xC9, 0xC2, 0xBC, 0xFF, 
    0xD3, 0xD4, 0xCF, 0xFF, 0xD8, 0xD9, 0xD4, 0xFF, 0xD2, 0xD4, 0xD1, 0xFF, 0xD2, 0xD4, 0xD1, 0xFF, 
    0xD3, 0xD8, 0xD4, 0xFF, 0xD3, 0xD5, 0xD0, 0xFF, 0xC8, 0xC9, 0xC3, 0xFF, 0xF0, 0xEB, 0xE5, 0xFF, 
    0x8D, 0x80, 0x78, 0xFF, 0x3F, 0x28, 0x22, 0xFF, 0x4C, 0x2B, 0x26, 0xFF, 0x95, 0x70, 0x6A, 0xFF, 
    0x58, 0x35, 0x2F, 0xFF, 0x69, 0x4B, 0x43, 0xFF, 0x75, 0x5D, 0x53, 0xFF, 0x80, 0x6F, 0x65, 0xFF, 
    0xDF, 0xD8, 0xCE, 0xFF, 0xCC, 0xC9, 0xC0, 0xFF, 0xCB, 0xC6, 0xC0, 0xFF, 0x80, 0x7C, 0x73, 0xFF, 
    0xAC, 0xA5, 0x9F, 0xFF, 0xC0, 0xB9, 0xB1, 0xFF, 0xD8, 0xD1, 0xCB, 0xFF, 0xC4, 0xBD, 0xB5, 0xFF, 
    0xD0, 0xD2, 0xCD, 0xFF, 0xD5, 0xD7, 0xD2, 0xFF, 0xCA, 0xCC, 0xC7, 0xFF, 0xD2, 0xD4, 0xCF, 0xFF, 
    0xCD, 0xD2, 0xCC, 0xFF, 0xCB, 0xCE, 0xC7, 0xFF, 0xCB, 0xCB, 0xC3, 0xFF, 0xD9, 0xD2, 0xCA, 0xFF, 
    0xA9, 0x98, 0x90, 0xFF, 0x63, 0x48, 0x41, 0xFF, 0x8D, 0x68, 0x60, 0xFF, 0x92, 0x69, 0x63, 0xFF, 
    0xA5, 0x7F, 0x76, 0xFF, 0xBE, 0x9C, 0x92, 0xFF, 0x82, 0x66, 0x5B, 0xFF, 0x7E, 0x6A, 0x5F, 0xFF, 
    0xE2, 0xDC, 0xD0, 0xFF, 0xC6, 0xC4, 0xB8, 0xFF, 0xCF, 0xCB, 0xC2, 0xFF, 0x83, 0x7F, 0x74, 0xFF, 
    0xA8, 0xA1, 0x99, 0xFF, 0xC0, 0xB9, 0xAF, 0xFF, 0xD2, 0xCB, 0xC3, 0xFF, 0xBE, 0xB7, 0xAD, 0xFF, 
    0xCD, 0xCF, 0xCA, 0xFF, 0xC8, 0xCA, 0xC5, 0xFF, 0xD0, 0xD2, 0xCD, 0xFF, 0xCC, 0xCE, 0xC9, 0xFF, 
    0xC9, 0xCC, 0xC5, 0xFF, 0xC4, 0xC7, 0xBE, 0xFF, 0xC2, 0xC2, 0xBA, 0xFF, 0xC1, 0xBA, 0xB0, 0xFF, 
    0xAE, 0x9D, 0x95, 0xFF, 0x74, 0x59, 0x50, 0xFF, 0xA1, 0x7F, 0x76, 0xFF, 0x7C, 0x54, 0x4C, 0xFF, 
    0x7F, 0x59, 0x50, 0xFF, 0x85, 0x60, 0x57, 0xFF, 0x6A, 0x4C, 0x41, 0xFF, 0xC1, 0xAD, 0xA2, 0xFF, 
    0xD5, 0xCF, 0xC3, 0xFF, 0xC5, 0xC5, 0xB9, 0xFF, 0xD1, 0xCF, 0xC3, 0xFF, 0x83, 0x7F, 0x74, 0xFF, 
    0xA5, 0xA1, 0x96, 0xFF, 0xC0, 0xB9, 0xAF, 0xFF, 0xC7, 0xC0, 0xB6, 0xFF, 0xBF, 0xB8, 0xAE, 0xFF, 
    0xC8, 0xCB, 0xC4, 0xFF, 0xCE, 0xD1, 0xCA, 0xFF, 0xC5, 0xC6, 0xC1, 0xFF, 0xC9, 0xCA, 0xC5, 0xFF, 
    0xC6, 0xC7, 0xC1, 0xFF, 0xBD, 0xBE, 0xB6, 0xFF, 0xB6, 0xB6, 0xAE, 0xFF, 0xB8, 0xB1, 0xA7, 0xFF, 
    0xC9, 0xBB, 0xB2, 0xFF, 0x79, 0x63, 0x58, 0xFF, 0x4D, 0x2F, 0x25, 0xFF, 0x6E, 0x4C, 0x43, 0xFF, 
    0x7B, 0x56, 0x4E, 0xFF, 0x73, 0x52, 0x49, 0xFF, 0x47, 0x2B, 0x20, 0xFF, 0xDE, 0xCC, 0xC0, 0xFF, 
    0xF4, 0xED, 0xE3, 0xFF, 0xCB, 0xCB, 0xC1, 0xFF, 0xCF, 0xCF, 0xC5, 0xFF, 0x84, 0x81, 0x78, 0xFF, 
    0x9F, 0x9B, 0x90, 0xFF, 0xBE, 0xBA, 0xAF, 0xFF, 0xC9, 0xC2, 0xB8, 0xFF, 0xB8, 0xB1, 0xA7, 0xFF, 
    0xC8, 0xCB, 0xC4, 0xFF, 0xC7, 0xCA, 0xC3, 0xFF, 0xC8, 0xC9, 0xC4, 0xFF, 0xC7, 0xC8, 0xC3, 0xFF, 
    0xC4, 0xC5, 0xBF, 0xFF, 0xBD, 0xBC, 0xB7, 0xFF, 0xB7, 0xB7, 0xAF, 0xFF, 0xB1, 0xAD, 0xA4, 0xFF, 
    0xB4, 0xA7, 0x9F, 0xFF, 0xC0, 0xAD, 0xA6, 0xFF, 0x5D, 0x44, 0x3D, 0xFF, 0x6A, 0x4D, 0x47, 0xFF, 
    0x81, 0x64, 0x5E, 0xFF, 0x45, 0x2A, 0x23, 0xFF, 0x62, 0x4B, 0x43, 0xFF, 0x4C, 0x3E, 0x35, 0xFF, 
    0x6C, 0x69, 0x62, 0xFF, 0xB0, 0xB1, 0xAB, 0xFF, 0xE8, 0xE9, 0xE3, 0xFF, 0x9B, 0x9B, 0x93, 0xFF, 
    0xA1, 0x9E, 0x95, 0xFF, 0xBA, 0xB6, 0xAD, 0xFF, 0xC7, 0xC0, 0xB8, 0xFF, 0xBE, 0xB7, 0xAD, 0xFF, 
    0xC8, 0xCB, 0xC2, 0xFF, 0xC5, 0xC8, 0xBF, 0xFF, 0xC8, 0xC9, 0xC3, 0xFF, 0xC7, 0xC6, 0xC1, 0xFF, 
    0xBD, 0xBC, 0xB8, 0xFF, 0xBB, 0xBA, 0xB6, 0xFF, 0xB3, 0xB2, 0xAD, 0xFF, 0xAF, 0xAC, 0xA7, 0xFF, 
    0xC9, 0xC2, 0xBC, 0xFF, 0x8D, 0x82, 0x7C, 0xFF, 0x51, 0x3F, 0x3B, 0xFF, 0x34, 0x21, 0x1D, 0xFF, 
    0x27, 0x14, 0x10, 0xFF, 0x72, 0x5F, 0x5B, 0xFF, 0x90, 0x81, 0x7E, 0xFF, 0x10, 0x06, 0x04, 0xFF, 
    0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x28, 0x28, 0x26, 0xFF, 0x57, 0x56, 0x52, 0xFF, 
    0x9B, 0x98, 0x93, 0xFF, 0xC7, 0xC4, 0xBF, 0xFF, 0xC1, 0xBC, 0xB6, 0xFF, 0xB9, 0xB5, 0xAC, 0xFF, 
    0xCA, 0xCD, 0xC4, 0xFF, 0xC7, 0xC8, 0xC0, 0xFF, 0xC8, 0xC7, 0xC2, 0xFF, 0xC2, 0xBF, 0xBA, 0xFF, 
    0xC4, 0xC0, 0xBD, 0xFF, 0xBE, 0xBA, 0xB7, 0xFF, 0xC4, 0xC3, 0xBF, 0xFF, 0xC4, 0xC3, 0xBF, 0xFF, 
    0x5C, 0x5B, 0x56, 0xFF, 0x04, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x39, 0x2F, 0x2D, 0xFF, 0x86, 0x7A, 0x7A, 0xFF, 
    0x88, 0x7C, 0x7C, 0xFF, 0x77, 0x6D, 0x6E, 0xFF, 0x1D, 0x14, 0x15, 0xFF, 0x13, 0x0F, 0x10, 0xFF, 
    0x1B, 0x1C, 0x20, 0xFF, 0x11, 0x15, 0x18, 0xFF, 0x08, 0x09, 0x0B, 0xFF, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01, 0xFF, 
    0x0A, 0x09, 0x07, 0xFF, 0xC4, 0xC0, 0xBD, 0xFF, 0xBD, 0xB8, 0xB4, 0xFF, 0xB3, 0xAE, 0xA8, 0xFF, 
    0xC6, 0xC9, 0xBE, 0xFF, 0xC4, 0xC5, 0xBD, 0xFF, 0xC5, 0xC2, 0xBD, 0xFF, 0xC7, 0xC2, 0xBE, 0xFF, 
    0xC6, 0xC1, 0xBE, 0xFF, 0xC6, 0xC2, 0xC1, 0xFF, 0xB4, 0xB4, 0xB2, 0xFF, 0x24, 0x26, 0x23, 0xFF, 
    0x00, 0x02, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x19, 0x19, 0x17, 0xFF, 0x15, 0x13, 0x14, 0xFF, 0x2E, 0x2A, 0x2B, 0xFF, 
    0x2F, 0x29, 0x2D, 0xFF, 0x04, 0x00, 0x05, 0xFF, 0x12, 0x10, 0x15, 0xFF, 0x16, 0x17, 0x1C, 0xFF, 
    0x11, 0x14, 0x1B, 0xFF, 0x12, 0x15, 0x1C, 0xFF, 0x1A, 0x1B, 0x20, 0xFF, 0x16, 0x15, 0x1A, 0xFF, 
    0x07, 0x05, 0x08, 0xFF, 0x64, 0x60, 0x61, 0xFF, 0xD7, 0xD2, 0xCF, 0xFF, 0xAC, 0xA7, 0xA3, 0xFF, 
    0xC3, 0xC6, 0xBB, 0xFF, 0xC8, 0xC9, 0xC1, 0xFF, 0xC7, 0xC4, 0xBF, 0xFF, 0xC3, 0xC0, 0xBB, 0xFF, 
    0xC8, 0xC2, 0xC2, 0xFF, 0xC6, 0xC2, 0xC1, 0xFF, 0x0F, 0x0F, 0x0F, 0xFF, 0x01, 0x03, 0x02, 0xFF, 
    0x16, 0x1A, 0x1B, 0xFF, 0x14, 0x18, 0x1B, 0xFF, 0x14, 0x15, 0x19, 0xFF, 0x0E, 0x0F, 0x14, 0xFF, 
    0x0C, 0x0B, 0x11, 0xFF, 0x19, 0x18, 0x20, 0xFF, 0x17, 0x17, 0x1F, 0xFF, 0x14, 0x17, 0x20, 0xFF, 
    0x13, 0x16, 0x1F, 0xFF, 0x11, 0x14, 0x1D, 0xFF, 0x11, 0x14, 0x1D, 0xFF, 0x18, 0x18, 0x20, 0xFF, 
    0x17, 0x14, 0x1B, 0xFF, 0x07, 0x05, 0x08, 0xFF, 0xB9, 0xB5, 0xB6, 0xFF, 0xAF, 0xAB, 0xAA, 0xFF, 
    0xBF, 0xC0, 0xB8, 0xFF, 0xC3, 0xC4, 0xBC, 0xFF, 0xC4, 0xC3, 0xBE, 0xFF, 0xC0, 0xBF, 0xBA, 0xFF, 
    0xDA, 0xD6, 0xD5, 0xFF, 0x84, 0x82, 0x83, 0xFF, 0x01, 0x01, 0x03, 0xFF, 0x1A, 0x1B, 0x1F, 0xFF, 
    0x14, 0x17, 0x1E, 0xFF, 0x17, 0x1A, 0x23, 0xFF, 0x11, 0x14, 0x1D, 0xFF, 0x12, 0x15, 0x1E, 0xFF, 
    0x17, 0x17, 0x21, 0xFF, 0x14, 0x14, 0x1E, 0xFF, 0x17, 0x17, 0x21, 0xFF, 0x14, 0x17, 0x20, 0xFF, 
    0x15, 0x18, 0x21, 0xFF, 0x0F, 0x12, 0x1B, 0xFF, 0x16, 0x18, 0x24, 0xFF, 0x17, 0x17, 0x23, 0xFF, 
    0x19, 0x19, 0x23, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x07, 0xFF, 0x73, 0x72, 0x77, 0xFF, 0xBA, 0xBA, 0xBC, 0xFF, 
    0xC1, 0xC2, 0xBA, 0xFF, 0xBE, 0xBF, 0xB7, 0xFF, 0xC7, 0xC6, 0xC1, 0xFF, 0xBE, 0xBD, 0xB8, 0xFF, 
    0xD9, 0xD8, 0xD6, 0xFF, 0x6F, 0x6D, 0x6E, 0xFF, 0x03, 0x03, 0x05, 0xFF, 0x15, 0x16, 0x1B, 0xFF, 
    0x14, 0x14, 0x1E, 0xFF, 0x11, 0x13, 0x1F, 0xFF, 0x13, 0x17, 0x23, 0xFF, 0x15, 0x19, 0x25, 0xFF, 
    0x14, 0x16, 0x22, 0xFF, 0x12, 0x14, 0x20, 0xFF, 0x15, 0x15, 0x1F, 0xFF, 0x15, 0x18, 0x21, 0xFF, 
    0x13, 0x16, 0x1D, 0xFF, 0x19, 0x1C, 0x23, 0xFF, 0x0C, 0x0E, 0x1A, 0xFF, 0x11, 0x13, 0x1F, 0xFF, 
    0x1A, 0x1A, 0x24, 0xFF, 0x07, 0x06, 0x0E, 0xFF, 0x31, 0x32, 0x37, 0xFF, 0xC4, 0xC5, 0xC9, 0xFF, 
    0xC1, 0xC2, 0xBA, 0xFF, 0xB9, 0xBA, 0xB2, 0xFF, 0xC5, 0xC4, 0xBF, 0xFF, 0xBB, 0xBA, 0xB5, 0xFF, 
    0xCD, 0xCC, 0xCA, 0xFF, 0x63, 0x61, 0x62, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x02, 0xFF, 0x17, 0x18, 0x1D, 0xFF, 
    0x1A, 0x1A, 0x22, 0xFF, 0x15, 0x17, 0x23, 0xFF, 0x15, 0x19, 0x25, 0xFF, 0x12, 0x16, 0x22, 0xFF, 
    0x11, 0x13, 0x1F, 0xFF, 0x16, 0x18, 0x24, 0xFF, 0x17, 0x1A, 0x23, 0xFF, 0x12, 0x15, 0x1E, 0xFF, 
    0x14, 0x17, 0x1E, 0xFF, 0x13, 0x18, 0x1E, 0xFF, 0x0F, 0x12, 0x1B, 0xFF, 0x0D, 0x0D, 0x17, 0xFF, 
    0x16, 0x15, 0x1D, 0xFF, 0x17, 0x14, 0x1B, 0xFF, 0x0A, 0x09, 0x0E, 0xFF, 0xB9, 0xBA, 0xBE, 0xFF, 
    0xBD, 0xBE, 0xB6, 0xFF, 0xBE, 0xBF, 0xB7, 0xFF, 0xC1, 0xC0, 0xBB, 0xFF, 0xB8, 0xB7, 0xB2, 0xFF, 
    0xCC, 0xCB, 0xC7, 0xFF, 0x54, 0x52, 0x53, 0xFF, 0x04, 0x04, 0x06, 0xFF, 0x10, 0x11, 0x16, 0xFF, 
    0x10, 0x10, 0x18, 0xFF, 0x14, 0x17, 0x20, 0xFF, 0x16, 0x1A, 0x25, 0xFF, 0x14, 0x18, 0x24, 0xFF, 
    0x12, 0x14, 0x20, 0xFF, 0x12, 0x14, 0x20, 0xFF, 0x15, 0x18, 0x21, 0xFF, 0x13, 0x16, 0x1D, 0xFF, 
    0x14, 0x19, 0x1F, 0xFF, 0x12, 0x17, 0x1B, 0xFF, 0x0C, 0x0F, 0x16, 0xFF, 0x13, 0x14, 0x19, 0xFF, 
    0x1E, 0x19, 0x1D, 0xFF, 0x1D, 0x18, 0x1C, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x04, 0xFF, 0x71, 0x72, 0x76, 0xFF, 
    0xC0, 0xC1, 0xB9, 0xFF, 0xBF, 0xC0, 0xB8, 0xFF, 0xBD, 0xBC, 0xB7, 0xFF, 0xB5, 0xB4, 0xAF, 0xFF, 
    0xC7, 0xC6, 0xC2, 0xFF, 0x56, 0x55, 0x53, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x02, 0xFF, 0x15, 0x16, 0x1B, 0xFF, 
    0x14, 0x14, 0x1C, 0xFF, 0x18, 0x1B, 0x24, 0xFF, 0x10, 0x14, 0x1F, 0xFF, 0x14, 0x18, 0x23, 0xFF, 
    0x17, 0x19, 0x25, 0xFF, 0x10, 0x12, 0x1E, 0xFF, 0x14, 0x17, 0x20, 0xFF, 0x14, 0x17, 0x1E, 0xFF, 
    0x10, 0x15, 0x1B, 0xFF, 0x10, 0x15, 0x19, 0xFF, 0x0C, 0x0F, 0x14, 0xFF, 0x0A, 0x0A, 0x0C, 0xFF, 
    0x0C, 0x03, 0x04, 0xFF, 0x14, 0x0B, 0x0C, 0xFF, 0x0C, 0x0A, 0x0D, 0xFF, 0x79, 0x78, 0x7D, 0xFF, 
    0xBB, 0xBC, 0xB4, 0xFF, 0xBC, 0xBD, 0xB5, 0xFF, 0xBC, 0xBB, 0xB6, 0xFF, 0xB6, 0xB5, 0xB0, 0xFF, 
    0xCC, 0xCB, 0xC7, 0xFF, 0x52, 0x51, 0x4F, 0xFF, 0x04, 0x02, 0x05, 0xFF, 0x16, 0x15, 0x1A, 0xFF, 
    0x11, 0x11, 0x19, 0xFF, 0x17, 0x1A, 0x23, 0xFF, 0x12, 0x14, 0x20, 0xFF, 0x11, 0x15, 0x20, 0xFF, 
    0x15, 0x17, 0x23, 0xFF, 0x14, 0x16, 0x22, 0xFF, 0x16, 0x19, 0x22, 0xFF, 0x12, 0x15, 0x1E, 0xFF, 
    0x10, 0x15, 0x1B, 0xFF, 0x15, 0x18, 0x1D, 0xFF, 0x19, 0x1A, 0x1E, 0xFF, 0x28, 0x24, 0x25, 0xFF, 
    0x73, 0x65, 0x62, 0xFF, 0x8A, 0x7C, 0x79, 0xFF, 0x55, 0x4F, 0x51, 0xFF, 0x4E, 0x4C, 0x51, 0xFF, 
    0xB9, 0xBA, 0xB4, 0xFF, 0xC2, 0xC3, 0xBD, 0xFF, 0xBC, 0xBB, 0xB6, 0xFF, 0xAE, 0xAD, 0xA8, 0xFF, 
    0xC2, 0xBE, 0xBB, 0xFF, 0x3E, 0x3D, 0x3B, 0xFF, 0x07, 0x05, 0x06, 0xFF, 0x07, 0x06, 0x0B, 0xFF, 
    0x0D, 0x0D, 0x15, 0xFF, 0x0C, 0x0F, 0x18, 0xFF, 0x18, 0x1A, 0x26, 0xFF, 0x16, 0x18, 0x24, 0xFF, 
    0x10, 0x12, 0x1E, 0xFF, 0x14, 0x16, 0x22, 0xFF, 0x15, 0x18, 0x21, 0xFF, 0x14, 0x17, 0x20, 0xFF, 
    0x11, 0x16, 0x1C, 0xFF, 0x11, 0x14, 0x19, 0xFF, 0x0B, 0x0B, 0x0D, 0xFF, 0x3F, 0x37, 0x35, 0xFF, 
    0xA4, 0x91, 0x8B, 0xFF, 0x91, 0x7E, 0x78, 0xFF, 0x69, 0x5F, 0x60, 0xFF, 0x5E, 0x59, 0x5D, 0xFF, 
    0xBA, 0xBB, 0xB5, 0xFF, 0xB9, 0xBA, 0xB4, 0xFF, 0xBA, 0xB9, 0xB4, 0xFF, 0xB2, 0xB1, 0xAC, 0xFF, 
    0xAB, 0xA7, 0xA4, 0xFF, 0x8D, 0x89, 0x88, 0xFF, 0x3E, 0x3C, 0x3D, 0xFF, 0x6E, 0x6D, 0x72, 0xFF, 
    0x41, 0x40, 0x46, 0xFF, 0x14, 0x14, 0x1C, 0xFF, 0x13, 0x15, 0x21, 0xFF, 0x16, 0x18, 0x24, 0xFF, 
    0x11, 0x13, 0x1F, 0xFF, 0x16, 0x18, 0x24, 0xFF, 0x11, 0x14, 0x1D, 0xFF, 0x16, 0x19, 0x22, 0xFF, 
    0x15, 0x1A, 0x20, 0xFF, 0x11, 0x14, 0x19, 0xFF, 0x10, 0x10, 0x12, 0xFF, 0x2B, 0x23, 0x20, 0xFF, 
    0x7E, 0x67, 0x61, 0xFF, 0x85, 0x6E, 0x68, 0xFF, 0x6B, 0x5F, 0x5F, 0xFF, 0xCB, 0xC5, 0xC9, 0xFF
};
```

Comment: Hi, you have understand me right. But this is the point i'm hanging. I have now a wxImage, but i dont know how I can convert it in a wxStaticBitmap or get it diretly into a wxPanel.